# Menuitem gets clicked but who is the parent?

Tags: c#, wpf, menuitem

I'm new to C# and WPF so this can be not so clever question. I've spent some time to get it this far and really not prepared to face following.

My code does build the menu based on data tables. It creates a menu up to two levels deep. And event handler is triggered each time main or sub item is selected. But the trouble is that I should know the main item (parent) when sub item (child) is clicked. How to gain that? This is the current handler:

```
    private void menu_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string sub = "";
        sub = ((System.Windows.Controls.HeaderedItemsControl)(e.Source)).Header.ToString();
        MessageBox.Show("Selection: " + sub, "Info", MessageBoxButton.OK);
    }
```

I saw `Item.Tag` could be the solution but I couldn't find a way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HeaderedItemsControl has a `Parent` property. This can be used to retrieve the element, which your menu item is a child of.

Comment: You may want to rephrase this into a bit more of an answer rather than a suggestion. Possibly add a description of what the Parent property is used for, and how it might apply to this situation.

Comment: Found the Parent property but is is a Non-public member. I try to read the value in event handler but I don't manage it.

Comment: Its definitely a public property. See the documentation [HeaderedItemsControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.headereditemscontrol(v=vs.110).aspx)